# Creating new app on Twitter causes "Rate limit exceeded" error

Tags: twitter

I have been trying to create an app for my Twitter developer account. Everything has been going good for a while now but now when I create a new app, I get a "Rate limit exceeded" error. I think this error comes with the API but I am only creating a new app. Any idea why I might be suffering from this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Bug seems resolved. I was able to create an App.

OP is creating an App and seeing this error in the Web UI. The App is used to get the required OAuth credentials. Only after you have those credentials you can start to use the API.
Apparently there is currently an error which prevents creation of apps.
Twitter acknowledged the problem and is investigating: https://twittercommunity.com/t/does-not-allow-me-to-create-a-new-app/32528/9

The HTTP Headers mentioned by DWRoelands are sent back when one is actually using the API and exceeding rate limits (as described in the document he linked)

Comment: thanks for the update. I have changed my answer to the current question to this one because this one has better details to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to start here: [REST API Rate Limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)

Definitely take some time to read and understand that document.  It will help you a great deal.

The responses that you get back from Twitter contain headers with important information about your current rate limit status:

- X-Rate-Limit-Limit: the rate limit ceiling for that given request
- X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
- X-Rate-Limit-Reset: the remaining window before the rate limit resets in UTC epoch seconds

By examining these headers, you can help your application make smart decisions about how often it makes requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not know that creating app go through the same scrutiny as well until I got a response from Twitter this morning.

Comment: When trying to create a new app through https://apps.twitter.com/app/new, I'm not seeing these headers on the response. Wish I were -- that would be quite helpful.

Comment: Looks like it's a off and on bug over at Twitter. On _creation_ of a new app, how can you reach the limit of the API?! For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395913/create-twitter-app-rate-limit-exceeded/29433823#29433823

Comment: This is a bug with twitter. I added an answer with more details.