# Create Twitter app - Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: twitter

When creating a new Twitter app at https://apps.twitter.com/ I receive the following error upon clicking submit.

"Error: Rate Limit Exceeded"

Comment: You are making too many queries per time unit.

Comment: It's a known bug over at Twitter. One of the Twitter staff just announced they're looking into it: https://twittercommunity.com/t/does-not-allow-me-to-create-a-new-app/32528/10

Answer (score 2):

According to other developers on twittercommunity.com, it seems to be recent bug affecting all new apps... hopefully there will be some solution soon

EDIT: I was trying to create new application for past two days and now I finally succeeded... It looks like it was just some bug and hopefully it's ok now... try it :)

https://twittercommunity.com/t/rate-limit-exceed-in-creating-new-app-at-apps-twitter-com/34985
https://twittercommunity.com/t/rate-limit-exceeded-when-i-try-to-create-an-application/21453/3

Comment: Still broken for me, from Switzerland (i'm mentioning my location because Eric William Dolan suggested that it might work from other locations)